# Problems with applying for a Schengen Business Visa to Iceland

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, business-travel, iceland

I have 2 questions:

I am remotely working from India for a U.S. based company which has no offices/branches in India.
I am invited to a company event hosted in Iceland.

**Question 1:**

In the list of documents required for a Business Visa, section 9 says:

> 9. A cover letter from the Indian organization or company containing following details; the applicant's identity; the purpose of the journey (meetings, conferences; training or business-related events); and the period and place of intended stay.

As the company doesn't have any offices/branches in India, what should I do?

**Question 2**

I am not considered an employee as they don't have offices in India. I have registered myself under sole-proprietorship.

Under section 7 for Self-employed, it says:

> 7. **Self-employed:** certificate of registration of the company.

Will the GST Registration Certificate (Form GST REG-06) be enough as a proof of business?

Comment: Your situation is indeed complex and you do not fall to any obvious category. As a result, you have to be creative, but the consular staff should be able to help. Have you tried contacting the consulate of Iceland in Delhi?